# OSX Sierra - Pygmentize sometimes not recognized

Tags: macros, minted

I've recently decided to switch to minted due to way better Python highlighting. I am having weird issues with minted sometimes not being able to find pygmentize on my Mac - never had the same issues on my windows 10 machine.

Steps I took:

1. Install local Tex Distribution - check
2. Install pygments > `pip install pygments` - check
3. Check if it's installed > `$pygmentize -h` > `Usage .../anaconda/bin/pygmentize` - check
4. Adapt Tex document > `\usepackage[chapter]{minted}`
5. Allow TexStudio to shell escape this document > `% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]`> then allow it to really use shell escape for this document
6. Now I am in a weird state - sometimes after starting TexStudio and setting the document I'll get > `Package minted Error: You must have`pygmentize' installed to use this package. \begin{document}`. When restarting TexStudio it works fine.

My document consists of one main document that includes the other chapters. Every chapter defines the tex-root like this: `%!TEX root = ../doc.tex`. The minimal example I've tried (which works flawlessly on win and sometimes on mac)

```
\begin{minted}{c}
int main() {
printf("hello, world");
return 0;
}
\end{minted}
```

I am grateful for any ideas you might have :).

Comment: This sounds like a PATH problem within TeXStudio. Try to typeset manually in Terminal.

Comment: I can only speak for my system after TeXStudio typesetting the document without hiccups again but this works as well - it is kind of a weird issue sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

It appear TexStudio is not looking for pygmentize at the right place.
So you need to create a symlink :

```
sudo ln -s "$(which pygmentize)" /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize
```